ISSUE with Flask and Flask Login : Please log in to access this page except i've succefully logged in
I have a problem that i can't solve, could you shed some light on it?
Here is my code, it seems ok for me but i keep getting an issue with the login process.
def role_required(*roles):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorated_view(*args, **kwargs):
            if not current_user.is_authenticated:
                return login_manager.unauthorized()
            if current_user.role not in roles:
                flash("You do not have access to this page")
                return redirect(url_for('login'))
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated_view
    return wrapper

class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, id_user, email, password, user_role, first_name, last_name, connected):
        self.id = id_user
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.role = user_role
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.connected = connected

    @classmethod
    def get(cls, email):
        formatted_email = email.replace("@", "%40")
        response = requests.get(f"{API_URL}/user/email?email={formatted_email}")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            user_data = response.json()
            return cls(user_data['id_user'], user_data['email'], user_data['password'],
                       user_data['user_role'], user_data['first_name'], user_data['last_name'],
                       user_data['connected'])
        return None

    @classmethod
    def authenticate(cls, email, password):
        user = cls.get(email)
        if user:
            hash_password = user.password
            if  bcrypt.checkpw(password.encode('utf-8'), hash_password.encode('utf-8')):
                return user
        return None

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(email):
    return User.get(email)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('usermail')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        if not email or not password:
            flash('Email or password cannot be empty.')
            return render_template('login.html')

        user = User.authenticate(email, password)
        if user:
            login_user(user)
            flash('Successfully logged in!')
            return redirect(url_for('traps'))
        else:
            flash('Login failed. Please check your credentials.')
    return render_template('login.html')Issue screenshot

@app.route('/logout')
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/traps')
@login_required
@role_required('Visitor','Staff','Admin')
def traps():
    # Collecting traps infos
    response = requests.get(f"{API_URL}/traps")
    cages = response.json()
    print(response)

    return render_template('traps.html', traps=traps)

Here is the issue :
issue screenshot
As you can see the user.authenticate seems to be ok but it still giving me the "Please log in to access this page " message.
Api connection is ok.

Can you check if you have received a session token in your browser after logging in?
